# Using a delegate having a string parameter for an event

Tags: c#, events, warnings

I want to use a delegate having a parameter of a string as event.  A warning is generated that I should declare the first params of my event as sender and the second params as Event Args.  I need to clean all my warnings.

```
//the declaration of my delegate   
public delegate void saisieDateTime(string dateTime); 
public event saisieDateTime EventSaisieDate;


private void button_valider_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Year.Text != "" && Months.Text != "" && Day.Text != "" && Hour.Text 
!= "" && Min.Text != "" && Sec.Text != "")
    Datestr = Day.Text + "/" + Months.Text + "/" + Year.Text + "  " + 
Hour.Text + ":" + Min.Text + ":" + Sec.Text;

  else
  {
    Datestr = "";
    MessageBox.Show("Format invalide");
  }
   //I call the event
  if (EventSaisieDate != null)
  {
    EventSaisieDate(Datestr);
    this.Close();
  }
  else if (EventSaisieDateTime != null)
  {
    EventSaisieDateTime(Datestr);
    Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.  You now have a choice, you can either do what the warning is telling you to do, or you can do what you want to do and use the signature of the event that you want.  The choice is yours, there really isn't anything for us to tell you.

Comment: What is the question? This is not Upwork...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As the warning says, you should follow the standard pattern for events, as laid out in [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern).

First, create your custom EventArgs subclass:

```
public class SaisieDateEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Date { get; }
    public class SaisieDateEventArgs(string date)
    {
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

Then your event is declared as:

```
public event EventHandler<SaisieDateEventArgs> EventSaisieDate;
```

And raised as:

```
EventSaisieDate?.Invoke(this, new SaisieDateEventArgs(Datestr);
```

You subscribe to it like this:

```
something.EventSaisieDate += HandleSaisieDate;
```

Where:

```
private void HandleSaisieDate(object sender, SaisieDateEventArgs args)
{
    // Look at args.Date
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I try with your example , I have another problem :when I call the "something.EventSaisieDate += HandleSaisieDate; " , a problem :"Aucune surcharge pour "Horo_EventSaisieDate" ne correspond au délégué "EventHandleer<DateProfilDay.SaisieDateEventArgs>.

Comment: @user10143829 I assume you're actually calling `something.EventSaisieDate += Horo_EventSaisieDate`? (Otherwise the question doesn't make sense). Make sure that `Horo_EventSaisieDate` has the signature `void Horo_EventSaisieDate(object sender, SaisieDateEventArgs args)`

Comment: yeah I try according to your example , private void Horo_EventSaisieDate(object sender,SaisieDateTimeEventArgs args)
    {
        dgv_jour_ferie.Rows[indexRow].Cells[indexColone].Value = args.Date;
    }   otherwise   I call it : Horo.EventSaisieDate +=Horo_EventSaisieDate();

Comment: Right, and `SaisieDateTimeEventArgs` is not `SaisieDateEventArgs`. Please update your question with *all* of your new code, as at the moment I'm just guessing at what you've written.